# Java8 streams : Creating a new object and adding it to list while iterating over another list

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists as follow

```
List<String> color = new ArrayList<>();
        color.add("red");
        color.add("white");
        color.add("pink");

List<Specification> specList = new ArrayList<>();
Specification soundSystem = new Specification("MusicSysten", "harman Kardon");
Specification price = new Specification("Price", "50000");

specList.add(soundSystem);
specList.add(price);
```

I want to create a new instance of specification object for each color item and add that to the specList. I tried something like this, But it's not working.

```
List<Specification> output = color.stream().map(c -> specList.add(new Specification("color", c))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the output I want here is something like

```
List<List<Specification>> output = [[(new Specification("MusicSysten", "harman Kardon"), new Specification("Price", "50000"), new Specification("Color", "red"))], [(new Specification("MusicSysten", "harman Kardon"), new Specification("Price", "50000"), new Specification("Color", "white"))], [(new Specification("MusicSysten", "harman Kardon"), new Specification("Price", "50000"), new Specification("Color", "pink"))] ]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I originally misunderstood your question.  Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're mapping to a new Specification so the List should be of type, `Specification`.  And you just map to an object and let the collector build the list.  Then you add that list to the specList.

Note that if you just keep using the same existing objects of `soundSystem` and `price` this may cause problems unless they are supposed to be immutable.  So I added a copy method to the Specification class to create new objects of each specification.  And since `List.of` makes immutable lists, I passed that to `ArrayList` to create a regular list.

```
List<List<Specification>> output = color.stream()
        .map(c -> new ArrayList<>(List.of(soundSystem,copy(), price.copy(),
                new Specification("color", c))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

output.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
[{MusicSysten, harman Kardon}, {Price, 50000}, {color, red}]
[{MusicSysten, harman Kardon}, {Price, 50000}, {color, white}]
[{MusicSysten, harman Kardon}, {Price, 50000}, {color, pink}]
```

Specification Class

```
class Specification {
    String attribute1;
    String attribute2;
    public Specification(String attribute1, String attribute2) {
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + attribute1 + ", " + attribute2 + "}";  
    }
    
    public Specification copy() {
        return new Specification(this.attribute1, this.attribute2);
    }
}
```

Comment: may be my question wasn't very clear. Updated my question

Comment: Here you go.  Hopefully it meets your requirements.

Comment: what do you intend by `.copy()`? why not use the `price` and `soundSystem` specs directly.. also seems like you can simplify to `.flatMap(clr -> Stream.of(soundSytem, price, new Specification("color",clr)))`

Comment: If I used those specs directly they would be the same object.   I just didn't think that would be a good idea unless they are supposed to be immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification, It looks like you want the following (assuming you are using java 9 or later and can use the convenient [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#immutable) factory method):

```
Stream.of("red", "white", "pink")
   .map(c -> List.of(
      new Specification("MusicSysten", "harman Kardon"),
      new Specification("Price", "50000"),
      new Specification("Color", c)
   )).collect(toList());
```

Comment: may be my question wasn't very clear. Updated my question

Answer (score 1):

@WJS solution will work. If you need the soundSystem and price to be added first though, you could make use of the foreach stream method. You could also initiate your ArrayList with the total size if its known.

```java
color.stream()
     .map(c -> new Specification("color", c))
     .foreach(specList::add);
```

Comment: may be my question wasn't very clear. Updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
List<List<Specification>> output = color.stream()
    .map(c -> Stream.concat(specList.stream(), Stream.of(new Specification("color", c)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(output);
```

result:

```
[[Specification(MusicSysten, harman Kardon), Specification(Price, 50000), Specification(color, red)], [Specification(MusicSysten, harman Kardon), Specification(Price, 50000), Specification(color, white)], [Specification(MusicSysten, harman Kardon), Specification(Price, 50000), Specification(color, pink)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 9 or higher, you can try

```
List<List<Specification>> output = color.stream()
     .map(c -> List.of(soundSystem.copy(), price.copy(), new Specification("color", c)))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `copy()` method on `Specification` class could be similar as @WJS has mentioned in his answer